# What is the best way of cutting out objects to create SVG files?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I got a PSD file from a designer. I want to get the icons and logos as SVG files, so I started to cut them out, and create a new PSD file for each of them.

[When I want to generate a SVG file](http://creativedroplets.com/generate-svg-with-photoshop-cc-beta/), I am just getting a question-mark:

[image]

**So, I cannot be the only person who has this need of creating SVG images out of a PSD file.**

I have Illustrator CC and Photoshop CC. I have a PSD file.

> What is the way to do it? What is the straight forward way of creating
>   SVG files out of certain objects inside a PSD file?

Comment: The only reason for that question mark, that I can think of, is if the svg contains a raster image and the link to the raster image is false. Although normally the assets generator would embed the raster image as base64. Remember that it can only export shapes as vectors. Also, svg support was only "fully" released to PS cc 2014 month or two ago, I think.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you confirm the icons are shape layers and not embedded image object?
2. That article is out of date and SVG is enabled by default in the latest Photoshop CC 2014.2.1 onwards.
3. You can also use [Extract Assets dialog within Photoshop](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/extract-layers-image-assets.html) to use an interface to extract assets from.
4. Alternatively, you can use a web service to [extract assets (including SVG), measurements, and more through Creative Cloud](https://assets.adobe.com/link/b7300f48-fd51-4a4c-acb9-adb18fbfa02d?section=extract) .

*(I work on these two services at Adobe)*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the type of person that jumps on every new version of Adobe products so I'm not sure whether Photoshop is actually capable of this or not.

In your situation I would export everything from Photoshop into Illustrator, run a Live Trace on the lot, and then save out as SVG.